# Обновление полей таблицы

Tags: postgresql, sql

Добрый вечер, ХэшКод. Подскажите пожалуйста SQL запрос с помощью которого можно обновить определенные поля таблицы, взяв значения из первых дочерних элементов?

К примеру есть такая таблица, tbUsers

|id|Login|Password|Name|Referer|email|

и у юзеров есьть таблица с дополнительными эмейлами

|id|user_id|email|

У юзера может быть несколько дополнительных эмейлов.

Как юзерам установить поле email равным значению первого дополнительного эмейла ?

|id|Login|Password|Name|Referer|email|

- |id|user_id|email| <--
- |id|user_id|email|
- |id|user_id|email|

|id|Login|Password|Name|Referer|email|

- |id|user_id|email| <--
- |id|user_id|email|

З.Ы. Сама таблица пользователей и дополнительных эмейлов нигде не применяется, взята в качестве примера.

Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Я бы в таблицу с "дополнительными" и-мейлами добавил ещё одну колонку типа boolean с названием `main`. И уже в описании логики приложения брал этот основной и-мейл. Это удобнее, чем апдейты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так должно под разными версиями работать:

```
update tbUsers u
set email=(select email from tbEmails e where u.id = e.user_id order by id limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Какая версия вашей СУБД?
`ROW_NUMBER()` Вам поможет, если ваша версия поддерживает.
Пронумеруете дополнительные email и заберете те, которым 1 присвоена
+ связанный `UPDATE`, если Ваша версия поддерживает)